Streamlit: keep fragment running while the page loads
I have a Streamlit UI with this code
import streamlit as st
import time

_LOREM_IPSUM = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **consectetur adipiscing** elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
"""

@st.experimental_fragment(run_every=0.2)
def counter ():
    if "i" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.i = 0
    st.write(f"counter: {st.session_state.i}")
    st.session_state.i += 1

def stream_data():
    for word in _LOREM_IPSUM.split(" "):
        yield word + " "
        time.sleep(0.2)

@st.experimental_fragment
def writter (stream, frame):
    frame.write_stream(stream)

counter()

frame = st.empty()

st.button("Stream data", key="but")

st.write("bottom text")

if st.session_state["but"]:
    writter(stream_data, frame)

The idea is that there is a counter that should always be running and, when the user presses the "Stream data" button, the text from the stream starts to appear ChatGPT-style. My problem is that, when the text is being added to the screen the fragment stops executing (that is, the counter freezes). How can I have a fragment running in parallel as the Python script executes?
